# How do I include a picture in a page element in Inquisit?

Tags: inquisit

I'd like to include a picture in a page element in an Inquest script: is this possible?

If so, how would you do it?

Comment: This question is a bit broad; if you're looking to promote/develop the tag, I'd recommend [contributing to its wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inquisit/info) rather than forcing a question.

Comment: @astroCB I've created a tag wiki also (it's under review). It's a legitimate question that I don't currently have an answer to. If you understand the language, I think you'd understand that this is an appropriate scope for a question. I plan to post some questions that are legitimate and when I find an answer, I'll post that answer. Over time I'll encourage others to post to stackoverflow. Basically, Inquisit currently just has a user forum that I find really painful after getting used to the StackExchange format.

Comment: +1, , inclined to give a user with this level of rep on multiple SE sites the benefit of the doubt. Plus the question does seem reasonable to me at least. Plus it could prove educational, I've never heard of this language.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Alright, that's fair enough: I didn't mean to sound standoffish, but it just seemed a bit vague to me.

Comment: @paisanco That's fine, but please don't base your decisions about questions on people: base them on the questions themselves.

Comment: @AstroCB no worries. And sorry if I sounded defensive. I'm not really clear on how you get a new tag started on stackoverflow. But it's just so frustrating programming in a language where the help is stuck in  hideous long-threaded forums.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim That makes sense; if you're looking to grow the tag, I'd recommend (as you've said you'll do) asking a few questions that could lead to long-standing canonical answers and letting it grow on its own, which is the entire point of tagging.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked 8 years ago...but I recently had the same question. So I thought maybe I could put something here in case someone in the future would have a similar question.

You cannot add a picture to the page element in Inquisit 5, but it would be possible in Inquisit 6. For Inquisit 5, you'll have to use  or .

Here's some discussion on this: https://forums.millisecond.com/Topic34836.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion [here](http://www.millisecond.com/forums/Topic4491.aspx).

In general, it seems that the `page` element only allows for simple text based instructions.

If you want to present images in instructions, there are a few options.

## htmlpage element

You can use the `htmlpage` element, which allows for instructions to be a complete formatted HTML file that can include images.

> The htmlpage element is used to define pages of text to be displayed
>   as instructions using the preinstructions or postinstructions
>   attribute. The htmlpage element is useful when complete control over
>   formatting and content of instruction pages is required, otherwise the
>   page element provides an easier way to display text with basic
>   formatting. The actual content of the page is contained in a separate
>   HTML file located on the local machine or the web.  [source](http://www.millisecond.com/support/docs/v4/html/language/elements/htmlpage.htm)

## Picture or picture and text in a normal trial

The other option is to present instructions as normal stimuli in the main trials of a block.
See for example, [the instructions in the sample script for the Iowa Gambling Task](http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/IowaGamblingTask/).

This can be either done as one integrated picture that includes text, or each image can be positioned as it's own stimuli.